# Is there a way to specify a tar file of docker image in manifest file for kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to specify a tar file of a docker image in a deployment manifest file for kubernetes? The nodes have access to a mounted network drive that will have the tar file. There's a post where the image is loaded by docker on each node, but I was wondering if there's a way just to specify the tar file and have Kubernetes do the loading and running.

--edit--
To be more exact, say I have a mounted network drive on each node, is there a way with just the manifest file to instruct kubernetes to load that image directly from tar file and not have to put it into a docker registry.

Comment: Not sure if I good understood you. You want to create a container based on tar? If you need this file, you can used `Dockerfile` and create your own image with this file inside container. However if you would like to `mount` specific folder in your deployment, to allow your pods access it you can do it, when you will specify `volume`. Its described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/) Please elaborate what you want to achieve and what [volume type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes) you want to use.

Comment: It will be a more standard setup to deploy a private Docker registry and push your images there.  It's functionally the same as what you're describing, but Kubernetes can use it without any special configuration.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm just curious if it is even possible or if manifests can only pull from registries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, Kubernetes can only access container images from a registry, not from a network drive, see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).

However, you could have a private registry inside your cluster (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry)). You could also have the images locally on the nodes (pre-pulled images) and have Kubernetes access them from there by setting `imagePullPolicy` to `Never` (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images)).

Answer (score 0):

You have provided quite limited information about your environment and how it would looks like.

Two things comes to my mind.

1. Use [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to download this file using `wget` or similar.

> Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:

- Init containers always run to completion.
- Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

That way you can be sure that tar file will be downloaded before your application will start. Example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hossainemruz/7926eb2660cc8a1bb214019b623e72ea)

2. Use [Mount Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

In your `deployment`, `statefulset`, `pod` (not sure what you are using), you can [Mount Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/) into pod. After that you will be able to inside pod specified path from volume. Please keep in mind that you have to use proper `access modes`.

To run `.tar` file you can use some bash commands like in [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).